# React native onLayout is working for android but not working for ios

Tags: react-native

Is onLayout working only for android ? in my chat application i used
`onLayout={() => flatListRef.current.scrollToEnd({ animated: true })}`
for lifting text chat showed in flat list above keyboard but it working fine for android but not working for ios ..what will be the solution for ios to lifted text chat above the keyboard for ios

Comment: It's possible onLayout is firing before the ref is populated on iOS. Maybe try a useEffect with the ref as a dependency?

Comment: can help me how to do it?